# Does it look unprofessional to have my name and all the titles of my website in lower-case?

Tags: business-writing

I'm planning to have all the titles of my website in lowercase, as shown in the picture:

[image]

I did it to fit the design of the black circle in the top left (Yeah stupid I know, just a designer's obsession for perfection).

I would like to know it it looks unprofessional (for instance, having my name written in lower-case as well as all the titles).

Comment: I think this is a design question.

Comment: @Standback I think whether it looks good or not (according to design standards) is a design question. Whether it is unprofessional or not (based on how I wrote things) it is a writing question.

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic. We are not a design community. Besides that I think the lower-case "alex chen" next to the circle is a good choice. "about", "contact" and "services" could be upper-case, but they need not. What hit my eyes is the lower-case "hi, there", no punctuation after "there" and an upper-case "My name ..." in the next row. Looks awful.

Comment: This is off-topic.  We address neither design issues nor the "look" of something (professional, etc.), but writing.  Try [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is on-topic. He's not asking about design (placement, position, color, font, white space, etc...); he's asking about capitalization and as Smithers pointed out, the "hi, there" is bad writing because it makes the content seem like a header. Decisions about how to distinguish headers or chapter markers in a written work should be welcome here. The fact that it's a webpage doesn't make it any less a writing question.

Comment: @patrick Finally someone understands my feelings.

Comment: @patrick I started up a discussion about this on Writers Meta if you're interested in taking part ...

Comment: @alexchenco - feel free to [discuss](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/337/20).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it looks fine.  I agree that "hi there" needs to be fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, very old, tired, kitschy, and unprofessional. e.e. cummings died a long time ago. When I see grown people still presenting themselves like this I want to pat them on the head. I immediately think:  young; fey; pretentious.

Comment: are you talking about writing things in lower case?